# How to deploy a symfony project without SSH and CLI access to production

Tags: php, symfony

Most of the hosting providers only have FTP access.

Is it possible/common to do a local installation of a symfony project (3.x or 4.x) and later upload it via FTP and manually create/update the database?

That question is holding me back on starting fully with symfony.

Thanks!

Comment: "Most of the user hosting I only have FTP access." Time to get better hosting. That was OK in the 1990s, but any modern host that doesn't offer SSH is one you should avoid entirely.

Comment: True... here in Argentina we are a little out dated but will gradually upgrade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This scenario it is not ideal but it can be done.

Actually we are going that way building everything with our continuous integration server and having just a zip file with everything ready for production to deploy to AWS Beanstalk so we can speedup the deployment process from minutes to seconds.

**Scenario**

Previous production version: /var/www/mywebsite-old

Current production version: /var/www/mywebsite

Next production version: /var/www/mywebsite-new

**Preparing the build**

You will need to prepare the app offline:

- set parameters.yml
- Environtment vars - I think they are copied to the cache during the $parameter->resolve()
- composer install
- composer dump-autoload
- cache:clean  --env prod
- delete the logs
- assets:install --env prod

**Uploading the build**

Once you finish your "build" you upload everything to your server preferable to  a non live location. At this stage your project is quite heavy so it may take time to upload, or it can partially upload so you do not want to break your production server.
Set the right folder permissions in var/cache and var/logs var/sessions as well as in the upload folders.

Example: /var/wwww/mywebsite-new/

**Swap the build**

Capistrano has a really interesting model for this.

1. Rename /var/www/mywebsite to /var/www/mywebsite-old
2. Rename /var/www/mywebsite-new to /var/www/mywebsite

**Run doctrine migrations**

You have a local setup to do your build, if you have to do some database migrations run them there connected to the production database

**Final recommendations**

This are many steps where things can go wrong and I really recommend you to automate everything to do an upgrade as well as a downgrade (rename the old version back to production) in case you did something wrong.

Options:

- Bash scripting / Makefile
- Capistrano
- Deployer

Comment: I like this answer, all information reflect real-world projects! But please don't forget that you have only FTP) How will you change folder permission through FTP? How will you run doctrine migrations through FTP?

Comment: You can change folder permissions via FTP and even you can run commands via FTP. Although this is usually limited to a really basic command set. This is why I recommended to run the doctrine migrations from their deployment process connecting from their dev machine to the database.

Comment: Symfony is a really powerfull php framework. PHP tried to avoid having to compile or doing a build, but that it is not the case in other technologies. Once you start working on bigger and bigger projects you will stop doing build + deployment on production machines and you will have a continuous integration process that separates it with Build and then Deploy. This allows you to build it once and deploy it to many servers in seconds instead of uploading the source on each server and each server doing it's own build which causes downtime or using massive amounts of cpu + memory

Comment: I know what you're talking about!) I do the same: build in jenkins + AWS CodeDeploy + Auto Scaling Group... But why did you decide that they have the same infrastructure? I think they have only web interface (c-panel) and FTP, no more...

Comment: Can you imagine all stuff you've described without SSH? But @user1505724 had told that they don't have SSH...

Comment: I do not use SSH for my deployments either. Actually I do only need SSH when the build on production fails which is rare. So if you do not do the build on the production server (which I'm implementing now) that removes most of the SSH user cases. I've explained the steps for doing it the best way possible without SSH. Why do you need to run those commands in production? It is not better to deploy something that has been build and tested instead of deploying the code, download the dependencies and "compiling/warming" it on demand?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, it's impossible  
Even you copy files through FTP you'll have problems with executing shell commands, like:

```
php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod
```

Hence - don't do it... It's painfull and incorrect...

Comment: That's not correct, you could just as well copy everything you have local to the remote server, setup the config files and db by hand. Then just delete `app/cache/prod|dev` or `var/cache/prod|dev` depending on your version. Symfony will then create the cache files on first http access. The only real *problem* is correctly serving the `public|web` directory if one has absolutely no other way of configuring the web server and the ftp access only allows access to the web root.

Comment: @Yoshi Have you ever tried this approach?) I've tried and it's nightmare... In general, all looks exactly like you've described but when it comes to real project life-cycle - it's just a hell...

Comment: Indeed I have, and I agree it's a total nightmare. I wouldn't advice it to anyone. But if the question is "is it at all possible" then I think the answer is "yes, though highly impractical".

Comment: @Yoshi In this case - agree with you! 