# Is it possible to run symfony 4 application on server without command line?

Tags: php, symfony

I had checked https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#common-post-deployment-tasks

Instead of what I need to do with command line, I have done manually. For example - vendor files just copied from my local machine, cache cleared manually, using still .env file, because cannot set environment variables.

First time it page loaded, but on next load I got error

> Attempted to load class "ContainerParametersResourceChecker" from
>   namespace "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Config". Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

I think same error was before clearing the cache. Of course we cannot clear the cache on each page load.

Is it not possible to fix it permanently or if it is - how?

Stacktrace:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException:
Attempted to load class "ContainerParametersResourceChecker" from namespace "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Config".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

  at var/cache/dev/ContainerWz8cB8L/srcDevDebugProjectContainer.php:357
  at ContainerWz8cB8L\srcDevDebugProjectContainer->ContainerWz8cB8L\{closure}()
     (vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php:95)
  at Symfony\Component\Config\ResourceCheckerConfigCache->isFresh()
     (vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory.php:42)
  at Symfony\Component\Config\ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory->cache('/home/dari/domains/dari.us.lt/public_html/symfony_4_persons_demo/var/cache/dev/srcDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php', object(Closure))
     (vendor/symfony/routing/Router.php:302)
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->getMatcher()
     (vendor/symfony/routing/Router.php:256)
  at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->matchRequest(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:109)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(EventDispatcher))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(array(object(DebugHandlersListener), 'configure'), array(object(ValidateRequestListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(SessionListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(ResolveControllerNameSubscriber), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(LocaleListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(TranslatorListener), 'onKernelRequest'), array(object(TraceableFirewallListener), 'onKernelRequest')), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:127)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:190)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:34)
```

**Update:**

By the comment I am still not sure what to do. Here was link in the comment:
[How to deploy a symfony project without SSH and CLI access to production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47943031/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-project-without-ssh-and-cli-access-to-production/47943527#47943527)

> set parameters.yml

Do not see such file.

> Environtment vars - I think they are copied to the cache during the $parameter->resolve()

I do not think I can set them without command line.

> cache:clean --env prod

Deleted cache folder contents manually in ftp.

> delete the logs

Does it really matter?

> assets:install --env prod

I do not think I use them.

I just set permissions to 777 on var folder in case something is wrong because of them. Its not a production server, so not caring too much about security, just need to run a demo.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47943031/how-to-deploy-a-symfony-project-without-ssh-and-cli-access-to-production/47943527#47943527

Answer (score 0):

You need a fully working build on your localhost with the production setup and then upload it. You know which is all the steps for your particular project to work locally. So clone your project in a new folder for the production setup and do all the steps. Once you are done, upload everything to the server and fix the permissions of the keys folders.

Note:
parameters.yml is the file where you set your symfony parameters like:

- database server address
- database name
- database username
- database password
- smtp server
- smtp username
- smtp address

but in symfony 4 it has been replaced by environtment vars.

Comment: I think I have done this, except that I did not set up production, but it should work as in dev environment, shouldn't it? And I am not sure what permissions should I set. And is this permission problem at all based on the error message I get.

Comment: WORST ADVICE EVER: Check which user use apache/php-fpm to run and change the owner of everything to that user.  Change all the files and folders of var/ recursively to 777. You have said it is just for a demo isn't it? :)

Comment: How do I find user which runs apache without command line? WHen I add shell_exec to php file, it gives 500 error. Yes, it is for demo.

Comment: Add a script with a <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: Added this. But where to look?